# When in Wireframe mode and selecting an egde, only the top is selected and not the whole vertices

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

I am watching this Blender tutorial, where switches to *Wireframe* viewport shading mode with <kbd>Z</kbd>, and he mentions when clicking it should select the whole vertices

https://youtu.be/6FuvpwZeXfw?t=2m12s

But when I turn on transparency, and select an edge, only the edge I clicked is selected not the whole side

https://i.gyazo.com/5bbfe7e209b5b52ab70f78004a3e34ef.mp4

How can I selected the whole side like this?

[image]

Comment: are you sure you are in edge select mode? what you describe looks like you're in vertex select mode...

Comment: Also, if you hold SHIFT and select another vertice, it will select both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the video (at 2m16s) he forgot to mention that just before selecting the vertice he is pressing the <kbd>C</kbd> key, **C** for Circle select.

[image]

He explains about <kbd>C</kbd> for Circle select at 2m30s as he is selecting the next corner vertice.